# Gmail calendar not synchronising with Calendar on OS X

Tags: macos, calendar, google-calendar

I use a MacBook Pro and found that my Gmail calendar doesn't sync at all. I guess it is because of the fact that this Gmail account also happens to be my Apple ID. My question is, how to synchronise Google's calendar with iCal when the Gmail ID is same as the Apple ID?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your Gmail account separately. Go to **System Preferences** → **Internet Accounts**, add a new Gmail account and enable the **Calendars** service to enable the sync.

Comment: Thanks @grgarside. I tried it multiple times, but it didn't work.